Zoom Changes Window, everytime someone starts Sharing Screen
Everytime someone initially starts sharing their screen on Zoom, my Mac computer switches from my regular running application to the Zoom Application.
Zoom goes full screen or maximized over other apps. Trying to listen to zoom audio in the background.
How can I prevent this?

Have you check to see if there is an appropriate setting within Zoom.

Can you clarify what you mean when you say that your computer "switches"? Do you mean that Zoom goes full screen or maximized over other apps? If so, this is pretty normal behavior for conference software. The call UI is often relatively compact, but when a screen share is broadcast the resulting window is usually much larger, in order to accommodate the new content.

hi @music2myear correct, trying to prevent this, thanks, I know its kind of standard, but not needed in my situation,

Have you tried the solution I propose below?

A quick web search showed this process:

In the Zoom client open Settings
On the left side click Share Screen
At the top of this window in the section titled "Window size when screen sharing" choose "Maintain current size"

This sounds like it doesn't apply to when others share a screen with you, but online reports indicate it does.
In older Zoom clients, try this:

In the Zoom client open Settings
On the left side click Share Screen
Uncheck the option Enter full screen when participant begins sharing screen. Most sources indicate this is the top option of that window.

